# NSComboBoxCell disable typing?

Tags: objective-c, macos, user-interface, interface-builder, nscombobox

I have a NSComboBoxCell that allows users to select an item from a list, but currently it also allows the user to type a value that they would like. I haven't been able to figure out a way to make it so that the user cannot type into the combo box (I just want them to be able to pick what is on the list). This seems like it should be relatively simple (even an interface builder option) but if so, I'm completely over looking it. Any ideas?

Note: This is for OSX and not iOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use an NSPopUpButton instead of an NSComboBox. The whole point of NSComboBox is that it provides both a text field that the user can type into and a popup button so they they can quickly choose options from a menu, generally as shortcuts for common values. NSPopUpButton just displays a menu. NSPopUpButtons are available in Interface Builder.

Comment: What about hiding the button and still have the popup list while typing?

Comment: What if I want the user to be able to type but the final value should render as a value from the dropdown? Similar to a search through the dropdown list func. Imagine my dropdown contains 200 items

Comment: @RaduSimionescu, you should ask a new question about that.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I came across the same issue.  I solved it by disallowing typing in the comboBox as follows:

```
func control(_ control: NSControl, textShouldBeginEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool {
    if control is NSComboBox {
        NSSound.beep()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```